Multithreaded usage of entityframeworkcore (DbContext), caused exception on model creation
I am creating a app-service on azure, that will consume from multiple topics on azure service-bus. The program contains a thread pr topic, and will process these into an MSSQL database.
The problem I was having was:
Meaning I would have an active consumer thread, pr topic, and each thread would need to write into a different MSSQL table.
This cause a problem, because I wrote the code like this:
using var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();

each thread would create a context, and use that within the scope of that threaded handling of a service-bus message consumption. At least this was the idea.
However, when I tried to use the context to determine if the object existed already, the program would throw an exception claiming that the context, was still en the process of generating the model.
I didn't know why, I thought I have either misconfigured the lifetime of the service, or didn't adequately implement some parallel processing technique.

The solution was to write:
using var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
await using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();

When you asynchroniously ask the scope to generate a model, you have actually wait for it to finish!
I feel very dumb for having overlooked this.
Anyway. I hope this helps others avoid spending too much time on debugging a problem like this.

I do not understand why it helps. Construction await using var context = .. just dsposes context asynchronously.

why not write a class that an DbContextFactory and creates the dbcontext it needs instead of pulling it from the DI container.

Without being certain @SvyatoslavDanyliv I belive it is because the await, actually forces the method inside to complete asynchroniously, before the remaining code is called.
I used to force the model loading, to avoid the exception, but this seems to correct the problem.
